# Jquery Ajax returning decoded XML attributes allow XSS

Tags: jquery, .net, xml, xss, ashx

I have a jquery ajax call that returns XML.  On the server we are encoding the xml attributes using the Antixss library from Microsoft, specifically calling Encoder.XmlAttributeEncode.

The results on the server are properly encoded

```
<data><item att1="Test" val="&lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;XSSFIX&quot;);&lt;/script&gt;" /></data>
```

But when the xml is returned to the client the xml is showing decoded

```
<data><item att1="Test" val="<script>alert("XSSFIX")</script>;" /></data>
```

The attributes are pulled out and appended to the DOM.  Looking at best practices on handling this situation.

**Update #1**
On the client I'm dynamically create a table and inserting the values of the xml attributes similar to this below.  Then finally I'm appending the table (string) to a div.

```
...
tableMarkup +=  "<tr><td>" + f.getAttribute('att1') + "</td><td>" + f.getAttribute('val') + "</td></tr>";

placeHolderDiv.append($(tableMarkup))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you actually need two layers of escaping:

1. HTML-escape the content that you want to concatenate into the HTML on the client
2. XML-escape the content that you're inserting into the XML attribute

The HTML-escaping should be done on the client (eg, use `.text()` instead of `.html()`).

The XML-escaping should be done by your XML library (eg, passing a string to `XAttribute`; you should not concatenate XML by hand)

Comment: I've updated my question to include more client details.  I believe then all I'd have to do is html encode the f.getattribute('att1') and f.getAtttribute('val') and it should be fine.  Any suggestions on the best html encoder for client side?

Comment: @maguy: Replace your string concatenation with a templating engine that automatically encodes text.